# Validation directive code is executed on every item in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, breeze, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am writing a single page application using Angular and Breeze. I have a set of entities displayed on my page using `data-ng-repeat`.

I am doing in place validation on the entities by having an "edit mode" div and a "display mode" div that are alternately hidden and shown using `data-ng-hide` and `data-ng-show`. One one entity at time can be in edit mode.

In the edit mode div, I have a bunch of inputs bound to the Breeze entity using `data-ng-model` and I am hooking in the Breeze entity validation using `data-z-validate` as described in the Breeze labs docs for their Angular validation directive:

http://www.breezejs.com/breeze-labs/breezedirectivesvalidationjs

The HTML looks like this (cut down for clarity):

```
<div data-ng-controller="payees as vm">
    <div data-ng-repeat="payee in vm.payees">
        <!--Display mode content-->
        <div data-ng-hide="payee.editing">
            <span>{{payee.name}}</span>
            <span>{{payee.addressLine1}}</span>
            <span>{{payee.town}}</span>
            <span>{{payee.postcode}}</span>
            <!--Some more markup here to switch to edit mode-->
        </div>
        <!--Edit mode content-->
        <div data-ng-show="payee.editing">
            <input data-z-validate data-ng-model="payee.name" />
            <input data-z-validate data-ng-model="payee.addressLine1" />
            <input data-z-validate data-ng-model="payee.town" />
            <input data-z-validate data-ng-model="payee.postcode" />
            <!--Some more markup here to save changes or cancel edit mode-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that each time I type in one of the input, the validate directive code is executed for *every input on every item* in the repeater - even the ones that are hidden. I can see this by putting a breakpoint in my debugger. When I have lots of entities, surely this will make the responsiveness of the page very bad. In my code example, if I have 100 payees, then the validation code will execute 400 times (one for each of 4 properties on each of 100 payees), when really, it only needs to execute 4 times.

My question is: Is there a way of making the validation happen only for the entity that is currently in edit mode, or equivalently, only for the inputs that are not hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For mutually exclusive conditions (for instance, a `ngShow` and a `ngHide` with the same value), you **should** use the [`ngSwitch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) directive, as recommended in the [AngularJS FAQ](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq):

> Note especially the powerful `ng-switch` that should be used instead of several mutually exclusive `ng-show`.

In your case, with `ngSwitch` and in "display mode", the `<input>` tags will not exist anymore, and the validation directives will not be executed.

```
<div data-ng-controller="payees as vm">
    <div data-ng-repeat="payee in vm.payees" data-ng-switch="payee.editing">
        <!--Display mode content-->
        <div data-ng-switch-when="false">
            <span>{{payee.name}}</span>
            <span>{{payee.addressLine1}}</span>
            <span>{{payee.town}}</span>
            <span>{{payee.postcode}}</span>
            <!--Some more markup here to switch to edit mode-->
        </div>
        <!--Edit mode content-->
        <div data-ng-switch-default>
            <input data-z-validate data-ng-model="payee.name" />
            <input data-z-validate data-ng-model="payee.addressLine1" />
            <input data-z-validate data-ng-model="payee.town" />
            <input data-z-validate data-ng-model="payee.postcode" />
            <!--Some more markup here to save changes or cancel edit mode-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```